# Oracle ORA-0095: missing keyword

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm experiencing some trouble trying to use the JOIN method for this problem. Perhaps I'm not using the right type of JOIN? I got the query to execute fine when I used the traditional method, the syntax of which is shown here:

```
SELECT cr.criminal_id, cr.last, cr.first, c.classification, c.date_charged, cc.crime_code, 
cc.fine_amount
FROM criminals cr, crimes c, crime_charges cc
WHERE classification = 'O'
ORDER BY cr.criminal_id, c.date_charged;
```

But when I try to use the JOIN method I get an error that says ORA-0095: missing keyword. I assume this is because I'm not being specific enough with the JOIN keyword? But I don't know what (if anything) I'm supposed to put in front of it. Here's the code that's giving me the error:

```
SELECT cr.criminal_id, cr.last, cr.first, c.classification, c.date_charged, cc.crime_code
cc.fine_amount
FROM criminals cr JOIN crimes c (using criminal_id)
JOIN crime_charges cc (using crime_id)
WHERE classification = 'O'
ORDER BY cr.criminal_id, c.date_charged;
```

The problem says that I'm supposed to list the columns which I've already selected in the SELECT statement, and then to only include crimes classified as "Other" (designated by the 'O'). Then I'm just supposed to organize the list by criminal id and date charged. Fairly basic stuff (which is why it's driving me crazy that I can't get it to work!).

Comment: Your "traditional method" does not JOIN anything; it just selects unrelated columns from separate tables. If you're using Oracle, then the MySQL and SQL Server tags are not applicable - they're totally different products, and the three are **not** equivalent. Use tags that actually apply to your question. If you're not sure, *read the description of the tag* before using it. Search this site for `[oracle] JOIN` (including the brackets) - there are lots of existing questions that provide examples of the proper syntax. Here... let me do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is the parentheses *before* `using`.  The column list goes in parentheses.  In addition, you are missing a comma before `cc.fine_amount`.  Try this:

```
SELECT criminal_id, cr.last, cr.first, c.classification, c.date_charged,
       cc.crime_code, cc.fine_amount
FROM criminals cr JOIN
     crimes c 
     using (criminal_id) JOIN
     crime_charges cc
     using (crime_id)
WHERE c.classification = 'O'
ORDER BY criminal_id, c.date_charged;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37357) is an example of the error on a smaller query.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is almost correct, except that it said I couldn't use column qualifiers when using the USING clause. However, this did help me figure out the right solution, so I'm upvoting it. Thanks again!

Comment: @TomMcNish . . . I try to use table aliases in any table that has `join`s.  The `using` clause doesn't allow this, so it requires paying attention to the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is not a JOIN, it should just return the Cartesian product of those 3 tables.
You have to specify the condition after WHERE clause, to make it a JOIN query.

You can refer the below, for the JOIN using ON/USING clause.

[USING clause in oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790436/using-clause-in-oracle-11g)